Is it possible to have generated .protos follow the naming guidelines?
Field names in protos generated by gRPC code-first implementation in ServiceStack all use PascalCasing. Is anyone aware of any option or tweak to make them follow the style guide like as described here https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/style/#message-field-names ?

It's not currently configurable, but you can submit feature requests at:
https://servicestack.net/ideas
